# How to package an entire Angular application for re-use?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications

Let's say I have an API that I charge people to access.

I want to create a "reference" web app that other devs can integrate into their own website, which consumes data from my API.

Are there any architectural choices I can make that will simplify the use of my webapp for these other devs?

The reference web app will probably be implemented in Angular, but the sites it gets integrated into could be using any web frameworks (or none at all).
I can bundle up all of my javascript and css into single files, and I can ensure that I'm not polluting the global javascript namespace. Anything else I should be thinking about?